# Prevent usbhid from claiming USB device

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, kernel-modules, devices

Directly related: [Prevent claiming of novelty usb device by usbhid so I can control it with libusb?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13964/prevent-claiming-of-novelty-usb-device-by-usbhid-so-i-can-control-it-with-libusb)

I want to access an RFID reader (works as HID device) from a program that uses libusb-0.1. In the code, the kernel driver is correctly detached with `usb_detach_kernel_driver_np` (no errors), but is seems that whenever my program tries to access the USB device, the usbhid module reclaims it. The following error always appears in `dmesg`:

> usb 1-1.3: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by usbhid while 'MyProgram' sets config #1

I've added the following udev rule, restarted udevd and replugged the device, but without effect. It is supposed to blacklist the device from being used by usbhid.

```
# I anonymized the vendor/product IDs here
ATTRS{idVendor}=="dead", ATTRS{idProduct}=="beef", OPTIONS=="ignore_device"
```

Apart from dmesg output, I can see in `/sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/` that the device `1-1.3:1.0` is recreated every time, so the blacklisting doesn't seem to work.

Anything else I could try? The operating system is Raspbian (on a Raspberry Pi) with kernel 3.2.27.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've solved this part of the problem:

- `OPTIONS=="ignore_device"` was removed from the kernel ([commit](https://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/hotplug/udev.git;a=commit;h=cdae488a3fbca5a61b3f8ea0651730cfa2da9cb0))
- `blacklist usbhid` didn't do anything, not even blocked my keyboard
- A configuration file in /etc/modprobe.d with `options usbhid quirks=0xdead:0xbeef:0x0004` did not work because usbhid was not compiled as module

So, I added `usbhid.quirks=0xdead:0xbeef:0x4` to the boot command line (on Raspbian, that's in /boot/cmdline.txt) and usbhid does not bind the device anymore.

---

My original problem, however, still remains. I always get a read/timeout error when accessing the RFID reader the first time.

Comment: Do you know how i can find a list with quirks for a specyfic module ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved modifying the udev rules file like this:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="input", GROUP="input", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="4242", ATTRS{idProduct}=="e131", MODE:="666", GROUP="users"
```

And now I can read the RFID logger by using `libusb` functions.