# How to load custom kernel module?

Tags: kernel-modules, module

How to force linux kernel to load my custom module instead of default one ?
There is a file:

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.order
```

Seems like it is responsible to load modules in specific order. How it can be generated to prioritize my module or maybe it is enough to place it in **/etc/modules-load.d** for loading during boot and create udev rule binding hardware by productID and vendorID to this custom module ?

---

**Example:**

usbhid module is used for mouse and keyboard. I want my mouse uses my custom module instead of usbhid.

Comment: Why not just give it a different name?

Comment: Remove the existing one? Use `insmod` instead?

Comment: @Bib It will not change anything. Default module will still be loaded and binded e.g. usbhid module will be loaded instead of my custom mouse module (with different name).

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Can't do it. It is needed for another hardware

Comment: Can't use `insmod`? Why?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov sorry i misunderstand. Will simple insmod custom module stop from using current mouse usbhid module ?

Comment: Have you read  the man page? insmod is not modprobe and it's not automatic module loading.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov This is not what i am asking. Question is how to force not loading default kernel module and instead load  custom one on boot.

Comment: Add it to blacklist `/etc/modprobe.d/blah.conf` -> `blacklist module`? Boot with `blacklist=module` ?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Can't blacklist usbhid because it is used by keyboard. See example above

Comment: You're changing your question on the fly. **That sucks a lot**. Please think it through first next time. OK, normally it's not possible unless the particular module allows to blacklist devices or you need to patch the module so that it ignored certain devices. `usbhid` has this: `parm:           quirks:Add/modify USB HID quirks by specifying  quirks=vendorID:productID:quirks where vendorID, productID, and quirks are all in 0x-prefixed hex (array of charp)`.

Comment: You can ignore your mouse by using the `HID_QUIRK_IGNORE` quirk which is `BIT(2)`. Check this answer for more info: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55495/prevent-usbhid-from-claiming-usb-device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent usbhid from claiming USB device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55495/prevent-usbhid-from-claiming-usb-device)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov No I am not changing anything. All is written in the very first sentence: "How to force linux kernel to load my custom module instead of default one ?" I don't know what you didn't understand, but quirks may be helpful.